# R Can't access newly created data inside loop

Tags: r

(I apologize if this is a duplicate of a previous posting)

I am trying to create a data frame inside a loop but can only access it outside the loop.

In  the following code I can access the scalar "s" but G is only printed outside the loop. Is there some scopiong or environment issue that I am missing?

```
for(i in  1:3){
   xx <- c(11:20)
   yy <- c(101:110)
   s <- 321
   G <- data.frame(x=xx,y=yy)
   print("**** inside loop ****")
   s
   G
   head(G,n=2)
}
   s
   G
   head(G,n=2)
```

Output:

```
[1] "**** inside loop ****"
[1] "**** inside loop ****"
[1] "**** inside loop ****"
>    s
[1] 321
>    G
    x   y
1  11 101
2  12 102
3  13 103
4  14 104
5  15 105
6  16 106
7  17 107
8  18 108
9  19 109
10 20 110
>    head(G,n=2)
   x   y
1 11 101
2 12 102
```

Note that nothing is printed inside the loop but the same lines do print outside the loop. Why is that?

Comment: R by default with `print()` the value of expression when you type it at the console. The `for` loop is an expression that doesn't return anything (well, technically it returns an invisible NULL). The values inside the loop aren't evaualted at the top level of the console so they aren't printed. If you want to see the values, you need to explicitly call `print()` on them.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! A bit subtle..